# Newbie : using h264 to encode mp3 with static image higher quality?

Tags: mp3, youtube, h.264

I need to put an mp3 up on youtube and Odyssee with a static image that is shown from beginning to end.  Needs to be h264 to go onto Odyssee.  Works fine but the static image is of grainy low quality.  How can I improve the quality of the image?

This is what I am using (this is the default with some freeware (Fase audio converter on sourceforge)  that wraps ffmpeg):

-framerate 1 -loop 1 -i input.jpg -i input.mp3 -acodec aac -vcodec libx264  -shortest ouput.mp4

Thanks for any help

Comment: *"How can I improve the quality of the image?"* - You believe this is the result of compression rather than the image itself being low res/poor quality?

Comment: Please put answers in the answer section. You are encouraged to answer your own question. Don't forget to accept the answer when the timer allows it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the setting  -tune stillimage that seems to be made for my purposes, which is good.  Although it would appear that the graphic itself is of low resolution rather than the video encoding.